# Is it possible to use Scala's parser combinator to parse a JSON text file line by line?

Tags: scala, text-parsing, parser-combinators

Is it possible to use Scala's parser combinator to parse a JSON text file line by line?

I'm new to Scala. When reading the book "Programming in Scala", I'm interested in Scala's parser combinator
and intend to write a simple JSON parser as a practice.

I intend to read from a text file and parse the file content. By a little research I realized that reading
all the contents of the file into memory(such as `Source.fromFile("1.json").getLines.mkString`) and then feed that contents to method `parseAll` is not recommended.

So my question is: is it possible to read the text file line by line and then do the parsing in a line based fashion?

I searched online but couldn't find any clue.

Any hints are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't assume the JSON data to contain line breaks. It may all be on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
Source.fromFile("1.json").getLines.forEach
```

The iterator you get back is a `BufferedLineIterator` meaning it wont read all lines into memory by default.
The moment you call `mkString` you ask the iterator to read all lines and create a string out of them.

The only thing you should keep in mind that you need to be ready for JSON objects over multiple lines.

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Joe"}
```

or

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Joe"
}
```

should produce same object, but reading line by line example 2 is a bit more tricky

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `parse` method of Scala's parser combinator reads one string and do the parsing. My question is that fromFile("1.json").getLines gives me an iterator and I can only feed one line to method parse, which means parse method will only process one line at a time. Is there any way that I can do a "reduce/fold" style parsing?

Comment: assuming you only support first example from my answer:
```lines.foldLeft(List[JSONObject]()){case (l: List[JSONObject], s) => l ++ List(parse(s))}```